# Execute behind the scenes bash command from Java ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, macos

I'm using in windows:

```
builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", my_command);
Process p = builder.start();
```

i've tried to replicate that behaviour, just for `macOS`
i've tried theese and none of them have worked:

```
1. builder = new ProcessBuilder("bin/bash", "-c", my_command);
2. builder = new ProcessBuilder("osascript", my_command);
Process p = builder.start();
```

Will appreciate the help
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked for me:

```
builder = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", command);
Process process = builder.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

The paths you have are incorrect, they should be:

```
/bin/bash
```

and

```
/usr/bin/osascript
```